# How to go to login form(login.js) when click submit on the register form(register.js) in sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, touch, extjs

I'm trying to do a sencha touch app where the user first needs to register. After that, a pop up alert will say that you have registered and when the user presses the 'ok' button, the register form (register.js) will go to login form (login.js).

This is my register.js:

```
Ext.define('demo.view.Register',{
extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype:'register',

requires:[
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.field.Email',
    'demo.view.Login'
],
config:{
    title:'Register',
    iconCls:'user',
    url:'doRegister.php',

    items:[
        {
            xtype:'fieldset',
            title:'Registration!!!',


            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    name:'username',
                    label:'Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype:'passwordfield',
                    name:'password',
                    label:'Password'
                },
                {
                    xtype:'emailfield',
                    name:'email',
                    label:'Email'
                },
                {
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    name:'first_name',
                    label:'First Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    name:'last_name',
                    label:'Last Name'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype:'button',
            text:'Share',
            ui:'confirm',
            handler: function() {

                // This looks up the items stack above, getting a reference to the first form it see
                var form = this.up('register');

                // Sends an AJAX request with the form data to the url specified above (contact.php).
                // The success callback is called if we get a non-error response from the server
                form.submit({
                    success: function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Resgistered Successful!', function(btn, text){
                            if (btn == 'ok'){
                                var redirect = 'login.js';
                                window.location = redirect;
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    ]
}
});
```

This is my login.js:

```
Ext.define('demo.view.Login',{
extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype:'login',

requires:[
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.field.Email'
],
config:{
    title:'Login',
    iconCls:'user',
    url:'doLogin.php',

    items:[
        {
            xtype:'fieldset',
            title:'Please Login',


            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    name:'username',
                    label:'username'
                },
                {
                    xtype:'passwordfield',
                    name:'password',
                    label:'password'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype:'button',
            text:'Login',
            ui:'confirm',
            handler: function() {

                // This looks up the items stack above, getting a reference to the first form it see
                var form = this.up('share');

                // Sends an AJAX request with the form data to the url specified above (contact.php).
                // The success callback is called if we get a non-error response from the server
                form.submit({
                    method:'POST',
                    waitTitle:'Connecting',
                    waitMsg:'Sending data...',
                    success: function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Login Successful!', function(btn, text){
                            if (btn == 'ok'){
                                var redirect = 'Share.js';
                                window.location = redirect;
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put both of the forms inside one Container with a card layout (layout: 'card') and when you want to switch to the login form you can call setActiveItem(1) on the parent container.. It would be best to use a controller for this logic so you could have references to all of the containers/forms from that controller.

Answer (score 0):

on alert ok button press you can create your login page to the viewport and then navigate to the login page.
here is the code :

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Demo', "Register successfully", function(){
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('demo.view.Login'));
    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.getLogin(),{
            type: 'slide',
            direction: 'right'
    });
 });
```